# Entity Framework 6: create change tracking proxies with a new entity instance without having to replace existing constructors by DbSet.Create method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, change-tracking

We have an existing WPF application that was previously built with a DB-first approach with an old version of Entity Framework (with object context class). The application is developed assuming that change tracking proxies are always activated so changing a navigation property for example would update the foreign key automatically (default behavior of ObjectContext).

Now, we're migrating to Entity Framework 6 and using a `DbContext` class. We implemented change tracking proxies by making all properties virtual and so on. The only problem is, when creating new instance of an entity, we have to call `DbSet.Create` method for the proxy to be created. But we're already using constructors with parameters, and changing the call of constructors of dozens of classes to a static method that calls `DbSet.Create` would be very long process and difficult to do.

Is there any other **easier** way to create proxies with the situation that we're in now?

Comment: There's more perspective in getting rid of change tracking proxies I know that's a very big thing to do, but it'll make your code more decoupled than it's now.

Comment: Have you tried using DbContext.Attach(entity) or DbContext.Entry(entity).State = Added?